# Is it possible to use imagemagick-convert's histogram visualisation option without counting transparent pixels?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

Apologies if this is a duplicate. I've been Googling this for a day.

**Goal**

I have a cartoon-like image of a character on a transparent background (mix of transparent black and white pixels). (Think something like a Pikachu or a logo - a solid, non-square shape on a blank background.) The only data I'm interested in analysing are the colour distributions of the pixels within this shape. I want to do this for multiple reasons, including assessing the palette of the character. I would prefer to use ImageMagick's generated histograms alongside it right now, rather than manipulating the text output.

**Issue**

Using `convert image.png -alpha off histogram:histogram.gif` or similar results in a histogram where the RGB channels are very short due to huge spikes on the left and right. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNn9j.gif) ImageMagick can, say, replace the transparent pixels with a given opaque colour, but that predictably replicates the issue in another channel. [This is the result of filling the transparent pixels with #008000.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91Rj2.png) It seems to me this is because the image is at least 50% black/white pixels with opacity 0, way more than any other single colour.

**Alternatives Tried**

Quantising does not produce a remotely desired result, because the averaged colours are so much blander than the ones used in the picture.

I know I can take the metadata output of the histogram and exclude #FFFFFF, #000000, and so on.

However, I would ideally be able to use ImageMagick's inbuilt visualisation simply because it would make my life a lot easier at this stage and I would not have to build my own visualisations. So what I want is the visualisation without it having counted transparent (or specified colour) pixels towards the number of pixels in the image.

Is this possible within ImageMagick? If not, I'll just manipulate the text histogram.

Comment: I cannot think of any way to directly set a bin to zero in Imagemagick's histogram drawing operation. I think you can do that in Python/OpenCV histogram. So you may want to look into that.

Comment: Thank you! I will have a look at other tools for sure if this doesn't pan out shortly. I appreciate the recommendation a lot.

Comment: You can manipulate the text histogram. But then you would have to plot it your self. If on a Unix-like systems, then see my plot3D script at my web site, http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick. It can plot histograms as well as profiles.

Comment: Thanks! These are good answers. I really appreciate getting an answer from you in particular - I had a look at some of your histogram comparison scripts, but you're impressively prolific. :) Someone else also came up with a hacky (but good enough in its approximation) answer of replacing these pixels with a random colour each time and trimming the random noise off the bottom, but when I need to make a proper histogram rather than to test, plot3D seems ideal to stay within ImageMagick. Thanks again!